# How to access the content of a variable in argument?

Tags: bash, shell, variables, arguments, command-line-arguments

How do I access the access the contents of a variable passed as an argement to a bash-script?

Example: `sh myscript.sh PATH`. Now I want to modify the string inside `PATH`, but keep failing at accessing it!

Any ideas?

Edit: I need to be able to  access any variable, not just `PATH`

Comment: What do you mean by "string inside PATH"?  PATH is a string.  $PATH is a different string.  Are you asking about the string "PATH" or the variable named PATH?

Comment: Well, I want the string that `$PATH` would produce. More generally,  I want `$ARGUMMENTTOMYSCRIPT`

Comment: I can't think why you would want that except as a homework exercise. What are you trying to achieve that is simpler than just passing the variable?

Comment: The tags contain `bash`, but you're running the script with `sh`. Which one do you want to use?

Comment: @l0b0 Im using bash version 4.2.10

Comment: @Evgeni And what does `sh --version` tell you? If it's Bash, it should say so. If not, *you're not running Bash.*

Comment: Theres no such command. Only `bash --version`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
FOO=$(eval echo \$$1)
echo args: $FOO
```

gives:

```
$ foo.sh HOME
args: /home/bos
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work for you:

```
#!/bin/bash

ARG=$1
VAL=${!ARG}
echo $VAL
```

With that if you execute your script like this:

```
./myscript.sh PATH
```

It prints `$PATH` value on STDOUT.

Comment: Both possibilities give me `Bad substitution` on Ubuntu 11.10, bash v. 4.2, unfortunately :.-(

Comment: If you run your script with `sh`, that's no surprise. `sh` is *not* Bash.

Comment: @l0b0 What are you tryying to tell me? Its GNU bash.

Comment: I very much doubt it. This script works on my machine (just run `./script.sh PATH`, **not** `sh ./script.sh PATH`), running Ubuntu 11.10 with Bash 4.2.10. If you run it with `sh` you override the shebang line, running it as if it's Dash, which it's not. That's why you see "Bad substitution".